# Why isnt my spf being received in every header?

Tags: email, dns, gmail, email-headers, spf

Just setup my spf record on my server and getting confused.

I send an email from my now spf secured address (example@emailwithspf) to my gmail account (example@gmail), check the headers and it shows SPF worked and passed (Received-SPF: pass (google.com: xxxx etc) which is great and what i wanted...

However, i send an email from the same account (example@emailwithspf) to another email address of mine (example2@emailwithspf) and check the headers, it doesnt even show that it used or received the spf?

Any idea why?
Do only certain servers check against spf?

Comment: SPF is pointless on internal-only email.

Comment: You mean like same address to same address but with different user accounts?

Comment: example@spf -> example2@spf would stay within the same server, so what's the point of certifying that it came from the same place it's going to?

Comment: Well there isnt a point really, i just wanted to test that it was working and only had limited accounts to send test mail to, so as long as it worked to the gmail account, its working yeah?

Comment: most likely, yah. easy enough to set up other accounts (yahoo, hotmail, etc...) to test those as well.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing. Would you switch over to hardfail(-all) instead of softfail(~all) if it all works fine and passes the tests?

Comment: can't answer that... depends on your policies and how tolerant you can be of false rejections/acceptances